# SQL Server - Find Memory ALLOCATED vs. Memory ACTUALLY USED

Tags: sql-server, memory, buffer-pool, performance-counters

I want to find average Memory USED per day.

SQL server caches as much data as possible in RAM (Buffer Cache) - this is ALLOCATED RAM
But how much of this data does it actually read subsequently - this is USED RAM

Scenario:

1. Server with 128 GB RAM, 120 GB allocated to SQL
2. Day 1 : Run `SELECT * FROM table_120GB` (Copies 120GB from DISK into RAM, and Reads it from RAM)
3. Day 2-9 : Do Nothing
4. Day 10 : Run `SELECT * FROM table_120GB WHERE ID = 1` (Reads 1 GB from RAM)

Average Memory ALLOCATED = 120 * 10 / 10= 120 GB / day

Average Memory USED = (120 + 1)/10 = 12.1 GB / day

Which counter from `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` gets me this Memory USED value ?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: The only way to do this accurately is a pretty bad idea: drop clean buffers every night and see how much memory gets used each day. But I have to be honest; knowing this will get you nowhere useful.

Comment: @ErikDarling - *it will get me somewhere very useful* - reliably specing VM size when migrating to cloud. AWS/GCP/Azure have this weird scheme that you **HAVE to scale CPU along with RAM** . If our on-prem server is 16-core, 512 GB RAM, we can't have have the same specs on cloud, we need a 64 core machine on cloud to get up to 512 GB RAM, which is prohibitively expensive. Therefore, if SQL simply hogs 512 GB (as seen in all relevant memory metrics), but uses only 100 GB of it on a weekly basis, we can spec a 16 core, 100 GB VM on cloud to reflect real need and avoid wasting a ton of money.

Comment: @J.D. - see ^ for ur answer

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way though, which is why I asked my question / Erik's point too. Say you emptied the buffers every night, you may still find the entire table being loaded into Memory every day even though you're only reading 1/3rd of the data (if the execution plan of your query uses a scan). You instead should use traditional methods to monitor Memory pressure such as performance counters or other means such as Erik's [`sp_PressureDetector`](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_pressuredetector/) and see if you can reliably reduce what you're currently using on prem first.

Comment: @J.D. - i do not intend to empty my buffers each night and read in tables. my question was - which counters record what I want and what you're suggesting (*"reliably reduce what you're currently using on prem first"*). i have a feeling the sp_PressureDetector (and most other scripts I've found) interchangeably use the terms **memory_used <-> memory_allocated**, but it's this precise difference I care about. I was merely responding to Erik's comment that this info will not be useful. Maybe what he meant was that dropping buffers won't be useful to get what I need

Comment: My point, in addition to Erik's, is knowing how much data you read from Memory each day isn't really useful for your end goal. Using Erik's example on how to do that, I provided one reason why it's fruitless to do so: if you only read 1 GB of data from Memory but your execution plans requires the entire table to be read into Memory first, you still need more than 1 GB of Memory to support that query. So the fact of knowing you only read 1 GB of data from Memory every day does not tell you how to provision your server. Instead, you should measure Memory pressure per my previous comment.

Comment: @d-_-b no, I definitely meant that this isn't a useful data point for your end goal. Even if you only read 120GB into the buffer pool every 2-3 days, what do you think performance is going to look like on every 2nd-3rd day? I can't think of a nicer way to tell you that this is totally foolish.

Comment: @ErikDarling - **"what do you think performance is going to look like on every 2nd-3rd day"** - that's a cost-performance tradeoff you can leave up to the purse holders, especially if the alternative is paying for 96 cores $50K/month to get 512GB of RAM. There are several cases where sql happens to read in large tables that are only used once a month, and keeps them in there.

Comment: @J.D. - correct. but i'm OK with reading the entire table from disk into memory if that table is only needed rarely

Comment: @d-_-b this is still a totally naive approach, because it takes zero other memory consumers into account. I get what you're going for, but this is all wrong.

Comment: "*i'm OK with reading the entire table from disk into memory*" - I thought your goal was to reduce the amount of Memory provisioned?...If so, then you can't read the entire table into Memory at one time anymore. The point here is you won't be able to meaningfully determine how much Memory to provision based only on how much data you read from Memory each day because that's not a representation of how much Memory is required to service your queries which may cause more data pages to load off disk than you're actually consuming in the moment. It's *almost* an arbitrary statistic in this case.

Comment: @J.D. - i didn't mean read it all at once. i meant i'm ok with disk paging occasionally. my goal is to reduce memory provisioning. **"which may cause more data pages to load off disk than you're actually consuming in the moment"** - yes i'm fully aware and OK with this. i'm not looking for a solution that holds all my databases in memory all the time.

Comment: If you currently fit a 100 GB table in Memory but only consume 1 GB from it each day, you're not going to drop your Memory down to only 1 GB, so what number do you provision then?...no way to determine just off that metric without being arbitrary. And what about in more complex cases where you read 1 GB of that data on day 1, then 90 GB of it on day 2, etc? You're no worse off guessing a number to provision at that point. Again, you're better off monitoring your Memory pressure, and slowly reducing your current provisioning until you find a number that's still acceptable for query performance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no accurate way to examine a running SQL Server and determine how it would perform with less memory.  The best way is to test by configuring MAX SERVER MEMORY to drop the available memory incrementally and watch the effect on Page Life Expectancy and IO.

Basically you're trying to find the "sweet spot" where reducing RAM just starts to increase IO and reduce Page Life Expectancy.

[image]

But that takes work to do in a test environment and you might not want to do in production.

Microsoft has an assessment tool for Azure migrations that will *estimate* the correct target configuration.

[Identify the right Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, or SQL Server on Azure VM SKU for your on-premises database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-sku-recommend-sql-db?view=sql-server-ver16)

And while the recommendations are Azure-specific, you can translate that to other environments.  Even so, expect to test and adjust after the migration.

If you want to test with a smaller-than-recommended configuration use something like the [Database Experimentation Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) to capture and replay a production workload against a restored copy of your database and measure the performance impact of running with fewer cores and smaller memory.  But you should do this in the target cloud, because you also need to test the storage configuration too.